# Docker nginx container exists instantly

Tags: nginx, docker, dockerfile

I want to have some control over the official `nginx` image, so I wrote my own `Dockerfile` that adds some extra funtionality to it.

The file has the following contents:

```
FROM nginx
RUN mkdir /var/www/html
COPY nginx/config/global.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY nginx/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

When I build this image and create a container of the image using this command:
`docker run -it -d -v ~/Projects/test-website:/var/www/html --name test-nginx my-nginx`

It will exit instantly. I can't access the log files as well. What could be the issue? I've copied the `Dockerfile` of the official `nginx` image and this does the same thing.

Comment: what do you mean by "exit instantly"? You get back to the command line prompt? Or you don't see the container in `docker ps` ? In case of the former, try to remove `-d`. In case of the later you might want to do `docker ps -a; docker logs <last container id>`

Comment: When I run `docker ps -a` it's exited instantly after I try to run it. Thanks, I'll try that in a bit.

Comment: if your Dockerfile does not end with a CMD or ENTRYPOINT, and your run command does not run nginx, this is "normal"

Comment: can you post your `.conf` files? the relevant bit would be to run nginx in the foreground or with the daemon set to off. The official `nginx` image is already configured to run nginx like that: `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`.

Answer (score 6):

So I didn't know about the `docker ps -a; docker logs <last container id>` command. I executed this and it seemed I had a duplicated `daemon off;` command.

Thanks for the help guys ;)!

Comment: "docker logs <last container id>" helped figuring out the issue.